# Perform a simple calculation in NANT program

Tags: nant

I need to do a simple addition in NANT program like 1 + 1 =2. I am finding it difficult as every variable is taken as string by default in NANT. I have also tried using int::parse but it did not work.

Regards

Sarathy

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you can use [convert::to-int](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/convert.to-int.html). There's also an operator overview [here](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/expressions.html#operators).

I also found two examples that perhaps help to understand overall usage ([example 1](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=101), [example 2](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.dotnet.nant.devel/2004-09/msg00045.html)):

From example 1:

```
<if test=“${int::parse(UnitTestsResult) != 0}“>
  <fail message=“Atleast one unit test failed!“/>
</if>
```

From example 2:

```
<target name="repeat">
<property name="var1" value="0" overwrite="false" />
<echo message="${var1}" />
<property name="var1" value="${convert::to-int(var1) + 1)" />
<call target="repeat" if="${convert::to-int(var1) < 10}" />
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. However I did not use "conver::to-int" as it is deprecated but used int:parse instead. Thanks again.

Regards

Sarathy

Comment: You meant int::parse (the double-colon)

Answer (score 2):

```
<property name="a" value="1"/> 
<echo message="${int::parse(a) + 2}" />
```

Gives:

> [echo] 3